# Emacs 24.3 Cedet installation won't work: speedbar recursive load

Tags: emacs, cedet

I'm currently struggling to get CEDET working in my emacs .
Following the instructions from [A Gentle introduction to CEDET](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html).

I got the lattest version form the bzr repo (n°8250 snapshot of the 31March13), put it in mydotemacsfolder, compile the cedet directory with make,  then made the necessary changes in the .emacs:
and notably put `(load-file "~/.emacs.d/plugins/cedet/cedet-devel-load.el")` in the beginning of the config file

When I'm launching emacs I get:

```
error: Recursive `require' for feature `speedbar'
```

and when I'm trying the debug init, this is what I get

> Loading /home/adriean/.emacs.d/emacs-config.el (source)... Loading
>   /home/adriean/.emacs.d/plugins/cedet/cedet-devel-load.el (source)...
>   Loading /home/adriean/.emacs.d/plugins/cedet/cedet-remove-builtin.el
>   (source)...done require: Autoloading failed to define function debug

my emacs version is `GNU Emacs 24.3.50.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.4.2)` of 2013-03-26 on muntries, modified by Debian
and I precise I'm using `org-mode babel`for organising my config. (so orgmode is loaded before)

Comment: Can you try to load Emacs with minimal config, consisting from cedet load command? Something like `emacs -Q -q -l emacs-minimum.el`, and see what will happen?

Comment: Here is what I get
`("emacs"  "-l" "emacs-minimum.el")
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
Loading /home/adriean/.emacs.d/plugins/cedet/cedet-devel-load.el (source)...
Loading /home/adriean/.emacs.d/plugins/cedet/cedet-remove-builtin.el (source)...done
eval-buffer: Cannot open load file: ede/loaddefs
Package assoc is obsolete!`

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you compiled CEDET with `make clean-all; make` ?

Comment: yep, I made it, and retried again and got this time
(since I add many try, I dont remember for sur I add recompiled it), so I cleancompiled it, and retried again and got this time:

`...
Loading autoloads from CEDET development.                                                                                    
Parsing  *srecode-map-tmp* (LALR)...done                                                                                     
Loading /home/adriean/.emacs.d/plugins/cedet/cedet-devel-load.el (source)...done                                             
Package assoc is obsolete!    `

Comment: so now it loads without errors?

Comment: adding the specific lines of the configs, it allmost works;but I get 

`Exuberant CTags not found.  Found ectags that comes with Emacs`

have you an idea were does it come from?

Comment: It comes from `(semantic-load-enable-primary-exuberent-ctags-support)` - it's better to use `when` with it as described in article. But it's better to install the `exubertant-ctags` package - it exists in all distros. I'll update article tomorrow

Comment: Also one annexe question, how do you use in your minimal-cedet_config `semantic-default-submodes` ?
when i tried  `(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-mru-bookmark-mode)`  It generate an error, semantic-default-submodes symbol.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: that's very strange - this variable should be available after `cedet-devel-load.el` is loaded...

Comment: installing exuberant ctags fixed the problem. (I havent't saw your message, and was thinking than sinc i had ctags (the oter package that was okay).
I'll retry tomorrow for the `semantic-default-submodes`...

Comment: Problem solved! in fact everything was coming from a bug in my load path. (some path were redundant because of the subdirectory load i was misusing) cedet and default submodules works fine.  Mea stupiditas